# TCL to JSON: use of json::write aligned method

Tags: json, tcl

I am facing problem to aligned the json data into a single line while using `json::write`.

for example, tcl dict is

```
set arr {a b c d}
```

conversion into json

```
foreach {key value} $arr {
    puts [json::write string {*}$value]
}
```

output:

```
{
   "a" : "b",
   "c" : "d"
}
```

where to use `[json:write aligned]` to convert above output into `{"a" : "b", "c" : "d"}`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to alter the `indented` flag:

```
% package req json::write
1.0.3
% set arr {a b c d}
a b c d

% json::write indented
1
% json::write  object {*}$arr
{
    "a" : b,
    "c" : d
}

% json::write indented false
false
% json::write  object {*}$arr
{"a":b,"c":d}
```

Hmm, I see the values aren't quoted...

```
% for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $arr]} {incr i 2} {lset arr $i [json::write string [lindex $arr $i]]}
% set arr
a {"b"} c {"d"}
% json::write object {*}$arr
{"a":"b","c":"d"}
```

or, thanks to Johannes, skip the for loop

```
json::write object {*}[dict map {key val} $arr {json::write string $val}]
```

Comment: Use `dict map` instead of `for`?